# IOException: Connection reset by peer during file download

Tags: java

Recently we are facing an issue in production( Stacktrace is provided below). Need help on resolving that issue.
 I went through many questions and answers in SO and found that the root cause is :

> "The usual cause of this error is that you have written to a
>   connection which had already been closed by the other end"

But in Production it started occurring since last 2 mnths . Before that there was no issue. Also, there is no recent code changes.
 Need your help on finding the root cause of this issue.

**StackTrace :**

```
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException:     
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:492)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:124)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:172)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:139)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:197)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:41)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:320)
```

Code :

```
long size = 0;
 try {
            byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                out.write(buff, 0, len);
                size += len;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // 
        } finally {
        in.close()
        out.close();
        }
```

Exception thrown from `out.write()` line.
Please help

Comment: Are client and server on the same machine?  Any firewall changes?

Comment: Frankly speaking it's difficult to debug this, because connection is being closed from client side. It may be an antivirus program which is terminating the long open connections, some firewall rules, browser's plugin not responding, or forceful closing the connection by client. I would suggest to install wireshark and analyze tcp dumps

Comment: @ScaryWombat No. Those two are different systems

Comment: @Rehman Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VincentS No. I didnt